# TestCafe CLI doesn't logout successfully on website using auth0

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

When logging out of mat website that utilized auth0, after clicking on 'sign-out', auth0 never signs out.  The website just reloads the page.

I can successfully login. The issue I have is if I click out 'Sign-out', TestCafe running in CLI never signs the user out. The page is just immediately refreshed. When performing the same behavior within TestCafe Studio, everything behaves correctly - a user is brought back to the original landing page and the auth0 login overlay is populated.

Is this an issue with TestCafe CLI interface and how it is interacting with the website?

I've tried several different selectors, React selectors and browsers.

No errors are shown and the application successfully logs out

**UPDATE**:  Here is my TestCafe code

```
test.skip('Successful Logout', async t => {
   const cog = ReactSelector('CogMenu')
   await t.click(cog)
   const signout = ReactSelector('MenuItem');
   await t.click(signout)
})
```

here is the React website code:
[image: React Website code]

Comment: It looks like a TestCafe bug. Could you please provide a small example which I can run on my machine?

Comment: @mlosev, I've provided some code to help

Comment: Thank you for providing additional details, but I'm afraid this information is insufficient and we can't help much without a reproducible example.
Please provide us with a whole test scenario including the testing page URL so that we'll be able to reproduce this problem on our side.

Comment: @HelenDikareva, where I'm seeing the error is a proprietary website.  I cannot give you the direct URL.  I will need sometime to find a site that uses auth0 authentication and see if I can reproduce.

Comment: @HelenDikareva @mlosev - This seems to be an issue within my application ONLY if the login details are used within the `beforeEach()` and `await t.useRole()` functions... if I have the login process directly within the `test()` Methods itself, the auth0 fully works when logging out.

Comment: @TallKU it's still very difficult to provide any help without an example. If you cannot share your website url here you can send it at support@devexpress.com

Comment: I will send in an e-mail.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, we got your email. We need time to research the issue. I'll reply to you when we have news.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Please follow this thread for details: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3780.

The fix was included in TestCafe [v1.5.0](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v150-2019-9-12).